# iPhone how to disable “No speakable content can be found on the screen”

Tags: iphone, accessibility

My phone randomly pops up “No speakable content can be found on the screen”. In response to some gesture. How do I disable this feature completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings → General → Accessibility → Speech and turn off Speak Screen.

This disables the two finger swipe down gesture from the top of the screen, which will speak content on the screen or show the message you're getting if there is no speakable content.